# Capture and re-send exchange server email not found errors

Tags: exchange

In my company we have a problem with deleted inboxes: they are still receiving emails but the exchange server is bouncing back an error.

I wonder if it is possible to catch these errors for an specific inbox and resend to the new addressee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, your best option is likely one of these two alternatives:

- Create a distribution group with that same alias to receive the emails and add the desired recipient to the group, or
- Add the address as an alias for the new desired recpient.
- Optionally, configure a single mailbox with aliases for all departed employees and use mailbox rules to route messages to the new recipients.

Comment: Thanks, some people in my company agreed with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Semicolon, Aliases limit will be increased to 400 by the end of November 2016. So you can create a new mailbox and add the delete mailbox as an alias. When you send emails to the deleted mailbox and the emails will be redirected to the new mailbox. Steps in the screenshot.
[image]